# Find by property not working as expected in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I have just cloned the example from https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-neo4j and ran the complete version. It fails with the stack trace below. Is this a fault from my side or is this a problem in the latest release?

Stack trace:

```
2019-02-18 15:37:39.059  WARN 5145 --- [           main]
org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Error executing query : Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ']' (line 1, column 106 (offset: 105))
"MATCH (n:`Person`) WHERE n.`name` = { `name_0` } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)-[r_t1:`TEAMMATE`]-(p1:`Person`) | [ r_t1, p1 ] ] ], ID(n)"
                                                                                                          ^. Rolling back transaction.
2019-02-18 15:37:39.066  INFO 5145 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-18 15:37:39.071 ERROR 5145 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:821) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:802) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:23) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ']' (line 1, column 106 (offset: 105))
"MATCH (n:`Person`) WHERE n.`name` = { `name_0` } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)-[r_t1:`TEAMMATE`]-(p1:`Person`) | [ r_t1, p1 ] ] ], ID(n)"
                                                                                                          ^
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil.newNeo4jError(ErrorUtil.java:62) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageDispatcher.handleFailureMessage(InboundMessageDispatcher.java:137) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:432) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:396) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:83) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:35) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.MessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageDecoder.java:40) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1336) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1127) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1162) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4    j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are running a Neo4j version older than 3.1. The feature Neo4j-OGM uses is pattern comprehension that came in with the 3.1 version (https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-3.1).